# Where can I find USB 2.0 drivers for Asus P5GL MX (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

Is it possible to use USB 2.0 drivers with the ASUS P5GL MX motherboard? If yes then where can I get the USB 2 drivers from? I cant seem to find them on the Asus site.

Comment: What is wrong with the Intel chipset USB drivers that are included with Windows 7? By this point in time you shouldn't need to install any "special" drivers to get USB 2.0 working on a motherboard with an  Intel chipse made within the last few years. They should already be included in Windows 7. No??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the drivers are [located here](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx?model=P5GL-MX&SLanguage=en-us).

It uses a standard Intel chipset and if you have any problems updating or getting direct from Asus, you may want to try download general chipset drivers direct from Intel which should do the job just fine.